# Blob or File System to store and retrieve heterogeneous file in a Web Application

Tags: mysql, angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc, blob

Good morning,
I'm designing a web application that uses technologies like Spring MVC, Hibernate, MySQL and AngularJS.
Now I find myself to solve the following problem. Suppose that to a product is associated one or more heterogeneous file (images, pdf, video etc ...) and and you have to manage both the upload and display of the files.
I had a look around the differences between the use of BLOB in the DB and the hybrid use of File System and DB.
My question is this: what is the best approach to use, taking into account the stack of technologies used and that remains (at least for the initial phase) deployed to a single server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in my opinion is to store files in file system and then store their paths in a database a varchar it worked well for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the past I have used this methodology in websites that were using php and MySQL but I had integrity problems because it was deleted a record from db and not from the file system and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are useful only in a few corner use cases. Most of the time, you'd want to store the files into the file system, which, unsurprisingly, was made exactly for that purpose :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using the blob does not have problems in terms of performance of the database and the backup?

Comment: That's what I mean. Unless you are absolutely sure that blob is the right thing for you, you should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

We went through a very similar process a few years ago, and chose to store the files in the database. This works fine for a small number of files. But consider the situation in a year / 5 years / 10 years and how many files you will have. They take up a lot of space in the database, which affects performance and backup/restore times.
We're now trying to move them out of the database and onto the filesystem and it is a lot harder than putting them in the filesystem to start with (as it is now deeply ingrained in our applications).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So you tell me that in the long term and with a modest amount of data Blob begins to create problems and is therefore preferable to store on the file system right?

Comment: that's right. unless you are **absolutely** sure that there will only ever be a small number of images, I would put them on the filesystem up front and do the development to make that work now, as it will save a lot of time, effort and problems later on.